# How to use properties of a qml file which is in different directory than main.qml. I am trying to use qmldir, but not able to implement it

Tags: python-2.7, qt, pyqt5, qml, pyside6

**File Structure**

```
 Common 
 -imports
   -Style.qml
 Main.qml
 main.py
 qmldir
```

Main.qml

```
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard
import QtQuick.Layouts
import "Commmon/imports"


Window {
        
    id: mainWindow
    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.Window
    height: 1080
    visibility: Window.FullScreen
    visible: true
    width: 1920
    title: qsTr("TMD_Visu")
    ColumnLayout{
        spacing: 10
        Rectangle {
            width: 200
            height: 100
            color: Style.backColor
            border.color: "black"
            radius: 10 
        }

    }


   
}
```

Style.qml

```
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Item {
    readonly property color avegareColor: "#486377"
    readonly property color backColor: "#ECECEC"

}
```

I have tried qmldir file, shown below:

```
module Common
Style 1.0 Common/imports/Style.qml
PopUp 1.0 Common/imports/PopUp.qml
```

- I am trying to import property of Style.qml in main.qml that is Style.backColor.
- Code is running, but it is not able to read property of **Style.qml**

Comment: Your qmldir is missing the singleton keyword. Also, the qmldir should be located in the directory of the module. But if you're using Qt6,  I highly advise against building that file by hand. Instead you should use CMake's qt_add_qml_module function to build a module for you. The docs are found [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/cmake-build-reusable-qml-module.html).

Answer (score 0):

In qt cpp we use "    qmlRegisterSingletonType(QUrl("qrc:///Singletons/Styles.qml"), "Styles", 1, 0, "Styles");"
this line for singleton
try using this in your main.py or similar to this.
use "import Styles 1.0" this import
and you will get variable like "Styles.avegareColor"